# mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Here is my code, which is to retrieve the information from mysql using json and ajax, but somehow it is not working, anyone can help to fix this?

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; 
    $username="Practical4"; 
    $password="1234"; 
    $db_name="Practical4"; 

    $con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql = "select * from comment where name='$name'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            $json['comment'][]=$row;
        }
    }
    mysql_close($db_name);
    echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Besides, how can I display each record line by line?

Comment: add errors with your question

Comment: mysql_close($con); ok?

Comment: Use this mysql_close($con); try to use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: mysql_close($db_name); remove $db_name and put $con;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of

```
mysql_close($db_name);
```

use

```
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

[see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)

you need to close connection not db name so `mysql_close($con);`

cheking your code to debug is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide the link_identifier in the [`mysql_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)

try this:

```
mysql_close($con);
```

`mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

you also do not need quotes in php variable.

replace

```
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

by:

```
$con=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `mysql_close($con);` instead of `mysql_close($db_name);`

mysql_*, is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) as of PHP v5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

Use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/mysqli) function or [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Read Oracle [Converting to MySQLi](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi)